# Problem with imakeidx in xetex document

Tags: xetex, imakeidx, compilation-error

I am trying to create two indexes for a Malayalam book using xelatex. After trying a few other packages I came to imakeidx in which I could create an English article using both pdflatex and xelatex without problem. But, when I tried to use it for my Malayalam book, it did create two indexes, but both containing the same matter, namely, the names of the indexes, "name" and "subject" with the correct page numbers. I give a minimal example below. I would be very grateful if anyone could point out the mistake I am making here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\malayalamfont[Script=Malayalam,BoldFont=Rachana-Bold,AutoFakeSlant=0.4,HyphenChar="0,Mapping=tex-text]{Rachana}
\setmainfont[Script=Malayalam, Mapping=tex-text]{Rachana}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=സൂചികകൾ]
\makeindex[title=നാമസൂചിക,columns=2]
\makeindex[title=വിഷയസൂചി,columns=2]

\begin{document}

പദ്ധതിയുമായി സഹകരിച്ച പ്രധാന വ്യക്തികൾ ഇവരാണ്: എം.എസ്.ആർ.~ദേവ്\index{name}{ദേവ്,~എം.എസ്.ആർ.} (പദ്ധതി തലവൻ), വി.~മനോഹരൻ\index{name}{മനോഹരൻ,~വി.} (ഫാബ്രിക്കേഷൻ), എസ്. രാജു\index{name}{രാജു,~എസ്.} (മിഷൻ), ടി.സി. പ്രതാപ ചന്ദ്രൻ\index{name}{പ്രതാപ ചന്ദ്രൻ} (പ്രൊപ്പൽഷൻ)\index{subject}{പ്രൊപ്പ‍‍ൽഷൻ}, എസ്.~റാം സുന്ദർ\index{name}{റാം സുന്ദർ,~എസ്.} (ഘട്ടത്തിന്റെ ഉപ ഘടകങ്ങളുടെ ചുമതല),
\clearpage

എം.വൈ.എസ്. പ്രസാദ് (ആവിയോനിക്‌സ്)\index{subject}{ആവിയോനിക്‌സ്}, ജി.~എബ്രഹാം\index{name}{എബ്രഹാം~ജി.} (ഇലക്ട്രിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ)\index{subject}{ഇലക്ട്രിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ}, ജി.~രവീന്ദ്രനാഥ്\index{name}{രവീന്ദ്രനാഥ്,~ജി.} (ചെക്ക് ഔട്ട്), എൽ. മുത്തു (കണ്ട്രോൾസ്),  ജോർജ്\index{name}{ജോർജ്,~പി.വി.} (മെക്കാനിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ). 

\printindex{name}{നാമസൂചി}
\clearpage
\printindex{subject}{വിഷയസൂചി}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name the indices and to use the syntax `\index[<name>]{<term>}`. Also `\printindex` only takes an optional argument.

(I used a different font because I don't have Rahana.)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newfontfamily\malayalamfont{Malayalam MN}[
  Script=Malayalam,
%  BoldFont=Rachana-Bold,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.4,
  HyphenChar="0,
%  Mapping=tex-text,
]
\setmainfont{Malayalam MN}[
  Script=Malayalam,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]

\makeindex[name=name,title=നാമസൂചിക,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=subject,title=വിഷയസൂചി,columns=2]

\begin{document}

പദ്ധതിയുമായി സഹകരിച്ച പ്രധാന വ്യക്തികൾ ഇവരാണ്: എം.എസ്.ആർ.~ദേവ്\index[name]{ദേവ്,~എം.എസ്.ആർ.} (പദ്ധതി തലവൻ), വി.~മനോഹരൻ\index[name]{മനോഹരൻ,~വി.} (ഫാബ്രിക്കേഷൻ), എസ്. രാജു\index[name]{രാജു,~എസ്.} (മിഷൻ), ടി.സി. പ്രതാപ ചന്ദ്രൻ\index[name]{പ്രതാപ ചന്ദ്രൻ} (പ്രൊപ്പൽഷൻ)\index[subject]{പ്രൊപ്പ‍‍ൽഷൻ}, എസ്.~റാം സുന്ദർ\index[name]{റാം സുന്ദർ,~എസ്.} (ഘട്ടത്തിന്റെ ഉപ ഘടകങ്ങളുടെ ചുമതല),
\clearpage

എം.വൈ.എസ്. പ്രസാദ് (ആവിയോനിക്‌സ്)\index[subject]{ആവിയോനിക്‌സ്}, ജി.~എബ്രഹാം\index[name]{എബ്രഹാം~ജി.} (ഇലക്ട്രിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ)\index[subject]{ഇലക്ട്രിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ}, ജി.~രവീന്ദ്രനാഥ്\index[name]{രവീന്ദ്രനാഥ്,~ജി.} (ചെക്ക് ഔട്ട്), എൽ. മുത്തു (കണ്ട്രോൾസ്),  ജോർജ്\index[name]{ജോർജ്,~പി.വി.} (മെക്കാനിക്കൽ ഇന്റഗ്രേഷൻ). 

\printindex[name]

\printindex[subject]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder how good the sorting is here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can't tell. I *guess* it uses byte ordering.

Comment: yes it should be byte ordering. It could actually more or less work: the chars start all with the same bytes and the last bytes probably reflects the wanted ordering.

Comment: The sorting looks good. I have used makeindex before to create single indexes for more than one book and they have come out well.